# React Native Stack Navigation

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, native

I have ComponentOne which is a Parent of ComponentTwo.
Then i have ComponentThree and ComponentFour.
Question is i can easily Navigate between ComponetOne to  ComponentThree  and ComponentFour, BUT i am unable to navigate from a button in ComponentTwo which is a child of ComponentOne, i am using Stack Navigation in React Native, 
error: evaluating ( this.props.navigator ) Undefined is not an object

I have tried declaring const {navigator} at various places in ComponentTwo but nothing seems to work at help
Help will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Without any code its hard to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a luck, Just passed the 
as a props to ComponetTwo and it works now :)
I think we need to pass the navigation reference as a prop to child Component to access it from child component.
Thanks,